# Increment of counter on dynamic addition of rows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add the rows dynamically plus auto-increment of a counter.I want to start with 1 then 2 then 3 and so on . I have added my code on plunker ,in which every time the max value is getting in first column like 4 then 1,1,2,3.Where am i going wrong ?i Want it to be 1,2,3,4.

Here is the plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/GuDbJ3SHOPvWkHfNfd8E?p=preview

```
            var _counter = 0;           
        function Add() {
            _counter++;
            var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
            oClone.id += (_counter + "");
            document.getElementById("placeholder1").appendChild(oClone);
            document.getElementById("myVal").value=_counter;

        }

    <div id="placeholder1">
    <div id="template">
        <div>
        Value:<input type="text" id="myVal" placeholder="1">
        Quantity:<input type="text" placeholder="Qty">

            <input type="button" onClick="Add()" value="Click! ">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like this:

```js
var _counter = 0;

function Add() {
  _counter++;
  var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
  oClone.id += (_counter + "");
  document.getElementById("placeholder1").appendChild(oClone);
  oClone.getElementsByClassName("myVal")[0].value = _counter;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder1">
  <div id="template">
    <div>
      Value:
      <input type="text" class="myVal" placeholder="1">Quantity:
      <input type="text" placeholder="Qty">

      <input type="button" onClick="Add()" value="Click! ">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your original you are cloning your template with the same `id` for the input. So when you do `document.getElementById("myVal").value=_counter;`, you only get the *first* input. I changed it to use `class` instead and get the input with the appropriate class that is a child of the cloned node.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you have multiple divs with the id="myVal".  [The id attribute should be unique](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) on the page.  If not, your page will still load, but you may have unexpected behavior.

You are changing the id of the template div, but not the myVal div.